# Blank grub boot screen

Tags: boot, grub2

I have just installed ubuntu gnome 16.10, with encrypted LVM partition. Right after successfully finishing the installation process, I boot up with a blank grub menu.
I got to press enter or wait 5 secs to boot into ubuntu.
Please, I need some help to get the normal grub menu.
Here is a picture of my screen :
[image: picture of grub booting screen]

Comment: Is that picture supposed to be showing a blank screen?  If so, it can probably be removed from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) has served me well in the past when I had problems with GRUB. The easiest way is to create [bootable drive](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/), and boot directly from it. As the interface suggests, the "Recommended repair" usually does the trick and you don't have to do anything.

One thing that you may want to do before rebooting is to look at how the physical drives are partitioned and named. A very handy command for that purpose is `lsblk`. I wish I had known about that command a long time ago!

Comment: It's more like a comment till an answer to me :-)

Comment: @Ravexina, point taken and answer edited.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, could you please [edit] in additional details, like how to best leverage boot-repair for issues with your system?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try boot repair and see if it solves the problem

Comment: boot-repair did the job, i also recommend grub-custumiser for similar grub-related issues.

Comment: @KazWolfe, let me know if you have any other edits to suggest.